# Submit form with jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery

As per our project requirement we have developed the jQuery dialog and added 3 buttons

YES , NO and CANCEL

On Yes Button we required to submit the form 
but the form is not submitted 
Nothing Happen to YES and NO

code is as below

```
 $("#dialog-NurseTeam").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 430,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Confirmation',
        modal: true,
        buttons:[ {
            "text": "Yes",
            "click": function () {
              debugger; 
              document.getElementById("IsNurseTeamChanged").checked=true;
              document.getElementById("hdnCancelChecked").value="Yes"; 
              $(this).dialog("close");
               $form = $('#PatientNewVisitForm');
              $form.submit();

              }

            },
            {
            "text": "No",
            "click": function () {
            document.getElementById("IsNurseTeamChanged").checked=false;
            document.getElementById("hdnCancelChecked").value="No";
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        },
            {
            "text": "Cancel",
            "click": function () {
            document.getElementById("IsNurseTeamChanged").checked=false;
            document.getElementById("hdnCancelChecked").value="Cancel";
                $(this).dialog("close");

            } }]


    });
```

Please help me out to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of these lines:

```
         $(this).dialog("close");
         $form = $('#PatientNewVisitForm');
         $form.submit();
```

to:

```
         $form = $('#PatientNewVisitForm');
         $form.submit();
         $(this).dialog("close");
```

The form submit lines may not be getting ran because the modal is closed. Not entirely sure, but could be worth a shot. Hope it helps.